# 802.1x profile for wired connection without Lion Server?

Tags: macos, osx-lion, 802.1x

I’m trying to setup my wired 802.1x connection available from the Login window in Lion (to make possible login with AD accounts) and don’t have Lion Server for creation of the Login window profile. iPhone Configuration tool creates only user profiles. Is it possible to create Login window profile without having Lion Server somehow?

Answer (score 1):

All in all, I've got a profile generated by a guy with Lion Server and have edited it adding my personal information and certificate data (using Property List Editor & iPhone Configuration tool). That profile worked for me fine.

Comment: What settings did you use for the profile and such?

Comment: Using the iPCT, i've created a WiFi profile and added a certificate entity there. After that, I've opened this profile in Property List Editor tool together with dummy profile from Lion Server and drag'n'dropped certificate related fields to the dummy profile. Also, have modified some fields manually to get the final result. Do you need any concrete settings? Please, ask!

Comment: I reccomend you hit the "Edit" button on your answer, and put all this in. Add as much detail as you can, it helps you make a great answer, and earn rep

Comment: I'll try to find some time soon to post a full answer here